# Multi cloud PostgreSQL replication

Tags: postgresql, azure, google-cloud-platform

I have an Azure-managed PostgreSQL database.

I want to create a logical replica of it at GCP, (Google-managed, if possible).

At Azure, I've set the Azure replication support to Logical. However, this just seems to allow me to create replicas inside Azure. What I want is to create a replica in GCP.

If this was not Azure-managed, but self-managed, I would be able to create a tunnel from Azure to GCP and then do the WAL copy replication.

One might wonder: why? Because I don't want to be locked with one vendor.

If that cross-cloud replication is not possible, what's the easiest way to pull the entire database off (possibly not just the data with pgdump, but all its internals too).

While this question is Azure -> GCP, it seems other alternatives like GCP -> AWS or other vendors are also not supported. Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Cloud Replication from Azure Source PostgreSQL to GCP destination CloudSQL through Conventional Native Logical Replication is possible and I've tested that it's working. I'm sure that it would work for self managed database too.